# Is it safe to pass anonymous type to MVC ViewData.Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is it ok to do the following:

```
View(new {Object A, Object B})
```

Or should Object A and Object B be explicitly declared in a new type?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223713/ ?

Comment: yes, i suppose it is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although anonymous types are versatile for many MVC purposes, in this case I would use a regular named class, or at a push a dictionary (or the inbuilt one). Otherwise you will have to use reflection / `TypeDescriptor` to get the values out again.

Comment: Not really.  There are evil ways of casting an anonymous type and getting type safe access.  http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2007/10/01/casting-to-an-anonymous-type.aspx

Comment: @JaredPar: OK, doable:yes - but desirable?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's fine to do so. To get the values, you can use ViewData.Eval("PropertyName") and the existing Html helpers will work fine with them. The only thing you won't be able to do is get strongly typed access to the properties using <%= ViewData.Model.PropertyName %>

Answer (score 2):

By passing anonymous types you cannot have strongly typed views. You will also need to use reflection in your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to at least give them names:

```
var model = new 
{
    ObjectA = new A(),
    ObjectB = new B(),
};


view(model);
```