# razor view with anonymous type model class. It is possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, anonymous-types

I want to create a view using razor template, but I do not want to write a class for model, because in many views i will have many queries which will be returning diferent models.

For example I have a linq query:

```
from p in db.Articles.Where(p => p.user_id == 2)
select new
{
    p.article_id, 
    p.title, 
    p.date, 
    p.category,
    /* Additional parameters which arent in Article model */
};
```

I need to write a View for this query. This query returns a Articles.

Now I dont know how should looks like a model definition.

I tried to use this deffinition:

```
@model System.Collections.IEnumerable
```

But then I had an erros than fileds doesnt exists in object type:

*CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'addition_field' and no extension method 'addition_field' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found*

This is my model for which I do not want to write a next model. Of course

Comment: `@model System.Collections.IEnumerable<Article>`

Comment: That query seems to project an `IEnumerable` of anonymous types, not of `Article`

Comment: Can you explain more why you don't want to write a model? There are advantages in using model classes - e.g. you can use intellisense, you can make more use of partial classes and can add attributes for things like validation to the model classes.

Comment: This post is nearly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758612/simplest-way-to-do-dynamic-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3 which has an answer for you: This can not be done.  You need to loop over the anonymous enumerable and convert them to dynamic objects

Comment: @Stuart - my personal reason for not using model classes is that in almost all cases they aren't required, especially for view-only pages.  Not having them lets me adjust and play with the code very easily, rather than re-writing the model classes, having all the extra files, and what are generally headaches maintaining something that is not needed.   Now, if VS.Net (or resharper/refactorpro) made working with them super transparent, I would consider it.  The best I have found is deleting the model class, and having R! regenerate it based on the Linq query.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The short answer is that [using anonymous types is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758612/simplest-way-to-do-dynamic-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3/3766947#3766947), however, [there is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception/5670899#5670899), you can use an `ExpandoObject`

Set your model to
`@model IEnumerable<dynamic>`

Then in the controller

```
from p in db.Articles.Where(p => p.user_id == 2)
select new
{
    p.article_id, 
    p.title, 
    p.date, 
    p.category,
    /* Additional parameters which arent in Article model */
}.ToExpando();

...
public static class Extensions
{
    public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this object anonymousObject)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> anonymousDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(anonymousObject);
        IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (var item in anonymousDictionary)
            expando.Add(item);
        return (ExpandoObject)expando;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I wish I could upvote this more than once. `ToExpando` is a great idea!

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution if you are using C# 7.0+ (introduced in Visual Studio 2017+) is to use a tuple rather than an anonymous type.

Razor View: "_MyTupledView.cshtml"

```
@model (int Id, string Message)

<p>Id: @Model.Id</p>
<p>Id: @Model.Message</p>
```

Then when you bind this view, you just send a tuple:

```
var id = 123;
var message = "Tuples are great!";
return View("_MyTupledView", (id, message))
```

Comment: what a nice usage of tuples

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an even better solution:

http://buildstarted.com/2010/11/09/razor-without-mvc-part-iii-support-for-nested-anonymous-types/

This allows for nested anonymous types, which the aforementioned expando-object solution won't handle.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can't pass anonymous types but if you just want the values of the type you might pass an enumerable of an object array to view.

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<object[]>   

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div>   
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item[0].ToString()</td>
                <td>@item[1].ToString()</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace ZZZZZ
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {

                List<object[]> list = new List<object[]> { new object[] { "test1", DateTime.Now, -12.3 } };

                return View(list);
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: Not bad at all :-)