# 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1 but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable ERROR

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Controller

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
   try
   {
      using (var DB =  new CekTakipOtomasyonEntities())
         {
            var model = (from f in DB.FirmaCek
                         join k in DB.KullaniciHesap
                         on f.KullaniciID equals k.ID
                         select new
                         {
                             f.ID,
                             f.Tutar,
                             f.KayitTarihi,
                             f.VadeTarihi,
                             tutar = f.Tutar,
                             f.SeriNo,
                             f.Banka,
                             f.Sube,
                             f.Iban,
                             f.Kesideci,
                             f.CiroEdilen,
                             f.TeslimEden,
                             k.Ad,
                             k.Soyad
                         }).OrderByDescending(f => f.KayitTarihi).ToList();
            if (model == null) return View();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
    catch { return View(); }
}
```

View

```
@using CekTakipOtomasyon.Models
@model IEnumerable<FirmaCek>

@foreach (var firma in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="secili" value="@firma.ID" /></td>
                                    <td>@firma.KayitTarihi.ToLongDateString()</td>
                                    <td>@firma.VadeTarihi.Value.ToLongDateString()</td>
                                    <td>@Convert.ToInt32(firma.Tutar).ToString() TL</td>
                                    <td>@firma.SeriNo</td>
                                    <td>@firma.Banka</td>
                                    <td>@firma.Sube</td>
                                    <td>@firma.Iban</td>
                                    <td>@firma.Kesideci</td>
                                    <td>@firma.CiroEdilen</td>
                                    <td>@firma.TeslimEden</td>
                                    <td>@firma.KullaniciHesap.Ad @firma.KullaniciHesap.Soyad</td>
                                    <td><button id="btn_Guncelle" value="@firma.ID" class="btn btn-block btn-info">Güncelle</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            }
```

I think I am misrepresenting variable type in view, what is the solution? Thank you from now

Comment: `return View(model)` model here isn't exactly type `IEnumerable<FirmaCek>`. Since you're doing `select new { ... }` it's actually an anonymous type. You should create an explicit type and then add `select new MyViewType { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring your model as IEnumerable but try to use it with a List of anonymous types.

Your options are:

1. Declare it as IEnumerable of YourType and create instances of this type in your Select clause. Currently it creates an anonymous object.

Here's an example of non-anonymous creation:

```
                     var model = (from f in DB.FirmaCek
                                 join k in DB.KullaniciHesap
                                 on f.KullaniciID equals k.ID
                                 select new MyViewModel
                                 {
                                     ID = f.ID //add properties here                              
                                 }).OrderByDescending(f => f.KayitTarihi).ToList();
```

2. If you want to keep using anonymous object, use IEnumerable together with ExpandoObject like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612938/razor-view-with-anonymous-type-model-class-it-is-possible).

Answer (score 0):

`Model` must be known or understandable type in your view. Change it as

`@model IEnumerable<FirmaCek>` or `@model IEnumerable<YourModelTypeInYourController>`. `model` is sent by `Index` action and it should have same type in the view.