# @model dynamic in mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am just curious about "@model dynamic" in mvc 3. Correct me if I am wrong but if you use this on a particular view then in your controller you can do this:

```
public ActionResult RandomView(int number)
{
    if (number == 5)
    {
       ModelFive model = new ModelFive();
       return View(model);
    }

    if (number == 6)
    {
       ModelSix model = new ModelSix();
       return View(model);
    } 
 }
```

I there anything else I am missing with 'dynamic' keyword? Somehow i did not find any useful doc.

Comment: Make one view model with the properties needed for RandomView?

Comment: Actually I was not aware of dynamic keyword before. So at first I thought it is meant only for model in mvc 3 and now i have figure that its actually something more. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28DYNAMIC_CSHARPKEYWORD%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758612/simplest-way-to-do-dynamic-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3) question. it goes through using the `ExpandoObject` to create a dynamic model.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was not aware of ExpandoObject either before