# Viewbag RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can solve this error to pass data to the view by `ViewBag`?

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'name'

In Controller

```
var linq = (from c in db.Catogeries
            join a in db.Articals on c.Id equals a.CatogeryId
            select new  {name=c.Name,title=a.Title });
ViewBag.data = linq;
```

In View

```
@{         
     foreach (var item in ViewBag.data )
     {
          <p>@item.name</p>
     }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use custom classes instead of anonymous. `new CategoryModel{name=c.Name, title=a.Title}`

Comment: Stop using ViewBag for passing models about. Use a model to pass information. http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/12/asp-net-mvc-viewbag-is-bad/

Answer (score 7):

The *simplest* way to fix this error creating a class instead of using anonymous object and use strongly-typed model.

```
var linq = (from c in db.Catogeries
        join a in db.Articals on c.Id equals a.CatogeryId
        select new MyCategory { name=c.Name, title=a.Title });

ViewBag.data = linq;
```

In `View`:

```
foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<MyCategory>)ViewBag.data )
{
     <p>@item.name</p>
}
```

If you insist about using `dynamic` you can take a look at these questions:

[Dynamic Anonymous type in Razor causes RuntimeBinderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception)

[Simplest Way To Do Dynamic View Models in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758612/simplest-way-to-do-dynamic-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: yes creating view  model class is the solution and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652749/object-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-x) is one more accepted answer which helped me.

Answer (score 3):

here is how I resolved my issue and I hope this 
may help someone:

I created a Class:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public decimal EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryCode { get; set; }
        public string CategoryDesc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

At the Controller:

```
var query = (from c in context.EmployeeCategory
             where(c.EMPLOYEE_ID == 22)
             join a in context.Categories on c.Category_CODE 
             equals a.Category_CODE
             select new MyClass
                         {
                             EmployeeId = c.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                             CategoryCode = a.Category_CODE,
                             CategoryDesc = a.Category_DESC
                         });
return View(query);
```

At the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyClass>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
            @item.EmployeeId <b> - </b>
            @item.CategoryCode <br />
            @item.CategoryDesc <br />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually caused by setting the `Viewbag` value. In the process .NET always throws an internal Exception, and then Visual Studio breaks into the debugger.

**Solution:** make Visual Studio break only for exceptions in *your own* code.
Go to menu Tools/Options, select Debugging on the left, and check [v] the option "Enable Just My Code".

Comment: No, it didn't worked for me. To fix the problem I converted the object data 'ViewBag data' to the strong type  Like  "foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<WorksheetDTO>)ViewBag.subCategories)" using class Worksheet DTO.

Answer (score -2):

You just need to cast it.  The view doesn't have any idea what type the object is so trying to enumerate it won't work until you cast it.  Something like:

```
foreach (var item in (IEnumerable <dynamic>) ViewBag.data) { ... }
```

Sorry if format is off slightly, trying to do this on phone.