# return a Viewbag structured by anonymous method and use it in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC project with Entity Framework, the problem is I want to return data from `Entity` to a `viewbag` **but this data structured by anonymous method** (means I create manually the properties and their values that will returned to the viewbag), and the `Viewbag` will returned to a view, and I want to use these values saved in the `Viewbag`.

That what I try,

**Controller :**

```
public ActionResult SHOW()
{

    var x = XController.xx();

    ViewBag.DATA = x;

    return View();
}
```

**xx function :**

```
public static dynamic xx()
{
    var R = (from U in x_DB_Context.Con.UFs from P in x_Context.Con.FRMTRs select new { CODE = U.CD_UF, INTTL = U.NM_UF, FL = U.FL_UF, ANN = U.ANN_UF, STT = U.STT_UF, SMSTR = U.SMSTR_UF, COEF = U.COEF_UF, NBCTR = U.NB_CTR_UF, FRMTR = P.NM_FRMTR + " " + P.PRN_FRMTR }).ToList();

    return R;
}
```

**View :**

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.DATA)
{
    <tr>

        <td>@item.CODE</td>
        <td>@item.INTTL</td>
        <td>@item.FL</td>
        <td>@item.ANN</td>
        <td>@item.SMSTR</td>
        <td>@item.COEF</td>
        <td>@item.NB_CTR</td>
        <td>@item.FRMTR</td>
        <td>@item.STT</td>

    </tr>
}
```

When I try to access to this `view` I saw error page with a big header message contains **('object' does not contain a definition for 'CODE')**

[image]

Please any help, and a lot of thanks.

Comment: You really need to start by adding some breakpoints and debugging - for instance, what is the value of R just before the action resolves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create classes instead of using anonymous objects and use strong-type models.

In Model,

```
public class UP
{
    public int CODE{ get; set; }
    public string INTTL{ get; set; }
    public string ANN{ get; set; }
    public string SMSTR{ get; set; }
    public decimal COEF{ get; set; }
    public string NB_CTR{ get; set; }
    public string FRMTR{ get; set; }
    public string STT{ get; set; }

}
```

In Controller,

```
public static dynamic xx()
{
    var R = (from U in x_DB_Context.Con.UFs from P in x_Context.Con.FRMTRs select new UP{ CODE = U.CD_UF, INTTL = U.NM_UF, FL = U.FL_UF, ANN = U.ANN_UF, STT = U.STT_UF, SMSTR = U.SMSTR_UF, COEF = U.COEF_UF, NBCTR = U.NB_CTR_UF, FRMTR = P.NM_FRMTR + " " + P.PRN_FRMTR }).ToList();

    return R;
}
```

In View,

```
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<UP>)ViewBag.DATA)

                            {
                                <tr>

                                    <td>@item.CODE</td>
                                    <td>@item.INTTL</td>
                                    <td>@item.FL</td>
                                    <td>@item.ANN</td>
                                    <td>@item.SMSTR</td>
                                    <td>@item.COEF</td>
                                    <td>@item.NB_CTR</td>
                                    <td>@item.FRMTR</td>
                                    <td>@item.STT</td>

                                </tr>
                            }
```

If you insist about using dynamic you can take a look at these questions:

[Dynamic Anonymous type in Razor causes RuntimeBinderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception)

[Simplest Way To Do Dynamic View Models in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758612/simplest-way-to-do-dynamic-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: Glad to help you :)