# Using dynamic object in ASP.NET Core MVC view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dynamic-view

Let me start by saying that I know there are other ways to do this and I have already successfully done it other ways. But I got to wondering how to use `@model IEnumerable<dynamic>` in a view.

I have tried this in the controller:

```
var result = from p in _db.People
             join ps in _db.PersonSport on p.PersonId equals ps.PersonIdfk
             join s in _db.Sports on ps.SportCodeFk equals s.SportCode
             orderby s.SportName
             where p.LastName == "Orr"
             select new { p.FirstName, p.LastName, s.SportName };
return View(result);
```

With this in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
<h4>Sports played by @Model.First().FirstName @Model.First().LastName:</h4>
   @foreach (var item in Model) {
       @item.SportName;<br />
    }
```

And I get a runtime error

> RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName'

A breakpoint at the `<h4>` shows that model has the data:

[image: Auto variable showing expanded Model in View]

I tried using creating result as a `new ExpandoObject()` and got the same error.

Am I way off base here or attempting something impossible? I was thinking of a use case where you have many table columns but are only extracting a few. Yes, I know I could create a class and do it that way, or send the data in ViewModel/ViewData, but was wondering if this was an option.

Comment: What happens if you add a `.ToList<dynamic>()` to your LINQ? Or change `return View(result);` to `return View(result.ToList<dynamic>());`. Or changed `new { p.FirstName, p.LastName, s.SportName }` to `(dynamic)new { p.FirstName, p.LastName, s.SportName }`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried all of them and they give the same results. Actually the second option (```return View(result.ToList<dynamic>());```) gives a different run-time error saying the object does not contain a method for ToList, but the other two give the same error message as previously.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that [using anonymous types is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758612/simplest-way-to-do-dynamic-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3/3766947#3766947), however, [there is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception/5670899#5670899), you can use an `ExpandoObject`.

The whole working demo is like below:

1. Custom `ToExpando` method:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> ToExpando(this IEnumerable<object> anonymousObject)
    {
        IList<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();

        foreach (var item in anonymousObject)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> anonymousDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(item);
            IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

            foreach (var nestedItem in anonymousDictionary)
                 expando.Add(nestedItem);

            list.Add(expando);
        }

        return list.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

2. View:

```
    @model IList<dynamic>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>SportName</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.FirstName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.LastName
                </td> 
                <td>
                    @item.SportName
                </td>
            </tr>
    
        }
    </table>
```

3. Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var result = (from p in _db.People
             join ps in _db.PersonSport on p.PersonId equals ps.PersonIdfk
             join s in _db.Sports on ps.SportCodeFk equals s.SportCode
             orderby s.SportName
             where p.LastName == "Orr"
             select new { p.FirstName, p.LastName, s.SportName }
             ).ToExpando().ToList();
    return View(result);
}
```

Result:

[image]