# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, exception

I'm using two DataContext objects to return seperate AsQueriable() datasets then joining the two using linq. The data construction works perfectly however when I pass that combined dataset to the view, I'm getting the error 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'.

During a debug session I can clearly see that both the parent Model and each 'item' in the foreach loop has all the data and keys visible/accessible. I'm very confused.

Many of the other q&a's on stackoverflow.com that match this problem don't solve my issue and as a result would appreciate a fresh set of eyes and hopefully a solution to this problem.

Many thanks! - code time:

The data construction

```
        public ActionResult SplashImages()
        {
            var g = (from i in GetGallerySplash() join o in GetFestivals() on i.Festival equals o.ID orderby i.Rating descending select new {i.Photo, i.OwnedBy, i.Rating, o.Name });
            Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            return View(g);
        }

        private IEnumerable<Gallery> GetGallerySplash()
        {
            GallerysDataContext gdc = new GallerysDataContext();
            return (from i in gdc.Galleries orderby i.Rating descending select i).Take(15).AsQueryable();
        }

        private IEnumerable<Festival> GetFestivals()
        {
            FestivalsDataContext fdc = new FestivalsDataContext();
            return (from i in fdc.Festivals select i).AsQueryable();
        }
```

VSExpress's error screen:
[image: Exception screenshot]

Any guidance on a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-sharp-anonymous-type-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you create a single model to encapsulate both IEnumerable objects, e.g.

```
public class GalleryModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Gallery> Galleries { get; set }
    public IEnumerable<Festivals> Festivals { get; set; }
}
```

Then strongly type your view to match the model

```
...Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<GalleryModel>"
```

Then in your model, you can type-safely refer to each object, e.g.

```
<% foreach (var t in Model.Galleries) ...
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias86, I was just about finishing this exact approach as I saw your answer. You are exactly right of course. I did make a new Model for the combined datasets and now the page is working perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. We've had to deal with similar scenarios, so I've been where you've been :)

Comment: I believe this is called the **MVVM** (`Model View ViewModel`) design pattern. Basically you add another layer between your Model and View - a ViewModel - allowing you to better encapsulate your model into a more view-friendly format. Many people who use the MVVM pattern add another folder called `ViewModels` to their project, emulating the usage of the Model, View, and Controller folders, and place all their ViewModel classes within.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning anonymous type to display in view, hence the problems. Take a look at those questions:

- [Can I pass an anonymous type to my ASP.NET MVC view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223713/can-i-pass-an-anonymous-type-to-my-asp-net-mvc-view)
- [LINQ to SQL: Return anonymous type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type)

You can either wrap your anonymous type in actual class and use strongly typed view, or play with some dynamic magic. Linked questions cover those topics.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your for loop to:

```
<% foreach (dynamic t in Model) { %>
```

The use of `var` is causing the type of `t` to be inferred as `object`.

Comment: if `Model` is not `IEnumerable<object>` i would rather go for a static typed version and introduce a poco ... `dynamic` is basically pure reflection!

Comment: Hi Matthew, I have applied that change unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: the issue is that the anonymous type will not escape the scope of the  action method and the view only knows the Model as type object.