# how to pass LINQ from to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

This is my Linq  in Controller

```
 List<ProfitsModel> prof = new List<ProfitsModel>();

            var categories =
                from p in prof
                group p by p.IdCategory.Name into g
                select new { Category = g.Key, TotalUnitsInStock = g.Sum(p => p.Value) };

            return View(categories);
```

how to see this select in my view?

Comment: If your view is strongly typed, `Model`, else `ViewBag`.

Comment: you're trying to pass an anonymous type to your view. that's ok. possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223713/can-i-pass-an-anonymous-type-to-my-asp-net-mvc-view

Comment: What does your profitsmodel look like? Why are you creating a "prof" list and doing nothing with it?

Comment: from p in prof i doing here

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your building a collection of **Anonymous** object. What you should do is, Create a ViewModel and use that in your LINQ query by updating the projection part. So that instead returning a list of anonymous items, it returns a list of your viewmodel class instances

```
public class StockDetail
{ 
  public string CategoryName { set;get;}
  public int TotalItems { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your GET action method, update the projection part of the LINQ expression and load the result into a list of `StockDetail`

```
public ActionResult GetCategories()
{
   List<ProfitsModel> prof =GetCollectionOfProfitsModelFromSomewhere();
   var items= from p in prof
                group p by p.IdCategory.Name into g select new StockDetail
                   { Category = g.Key, TotalUnitsInStock = g.Sum(p => p.Value) };
  return View(items);
}
```

Make your view strongly typed to a collection of StockDetails

```
@model List<StockDetail>

@foreach(item in Model)
{
  <p>@item.Category </p>
  <p>@item.TotalUnitsInStock.ToString()</p>

}
```

Comment: I dont understand what i should have in controller after i make viewmodel

Comment: @user2026573: Return the collection to view. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a model to the view and add a list or enumerable property to the model. You can then foreach over the enumerable directly in the view and render out each item within a defined piece of HTML structure.

If your model is an anonymous type then you could can use ViewBag/ViewData to store the results.

Comment: @model IEnumerable<WHFM.Models.ProfitsModel>
this is in my view , but how to show the result of linq