# Add property and value to C# List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### The goal

Add property and value to List. I'm using C#/MVC 4/Razor.

### The problem

I have the following:

```
return PartialView("_CategoriesList", db.bm_product_categories.ToList());
```

Ok, all good here. My list returns me multiple columns from database and one of them is `Category_Name`. I want to "slugify" each category name with C# and then pass to view. I was thinking in something like this:

```
foreach (var categorySlug in db.bm_product_categories)
{
    db.bm_product_categories
       .Add({
              "Category_Name_Slugged":
              Helpers.Slugify(db.bm_product_categories.Category_Name)
           });
}
```

But, obviously, this syntax is wrong — I do not know what to do.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this , if you can make a copy of the data and work

```
var sluggifiedList = (from category in db.bm_product_categories  
select category.CategoryName.Slugify()).ToList();
```

else

```
(from categoryName in db.bm_product_categories.CategoryName      
select categoryName).ToList().ForEach  
(category_Name => category_Name = category_Name.Slugigy());
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this is pretty smart to decipher this in seconds.

Comment: Hello. In my view my model was `@model IEnumerable<BluMercados.Models.Data.bm_product_categories>` — And now, as it will be?

Comment: i think you dont have to too worry about where to place this internal class , u can create a new cs file and place this code or add this new class in any of the existing file , of course in the same project

Comment: @srsyogesh My question is: what I have to put on the first line of my View?

Comment: I havent learned asp.net yet :( so i am not sure what to specify in the View.

Answer (score 1):

You can project the altered model using LINQ, such as:

```
var sluggifiedProjection = 
  db.bm_product_categories
    .ToList() // Need to materialize here. Ensure any filters applied before this.
    .Select(cat => new 
      {
        CategoryNameSlugged = Helpers.Slugify(cat.Category_Name) 
        // .. + other fields of bm_product_categories needed by your view
      });

 return PartialView("_CategoriesList", sluggifiedProjection);
```

The creates a list of an anonymous class - you could obviously also create a new typed `ViewModel` class as well for `CategoryNameSlugged` and share this class with your View. See also [Can I pass an anonymous type to my ASP.NET MVC view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223713/can-i-pass-an-anonymous-type-to-my-asp-net-mvc-view)

**Update**

As per the linked post, you can either leave the projection as anonymous, and then in the Razor View, use a dynamic or reflection to access the `CategoryNameSlugged` property from the list, or alternatively (and preferably), you can use a strongly typed `ViewModel` class:

```
internal class SluggedCategoriesViewModel
{
    public string CategoryNameSlugged {get; set; }
    // Add any other properties from bm_product_categories that your view needs, e.g.
    public int CategoryId {get; set; }
}
```

And the projection now uses the strongly typed `ViewModel` class:

```
  .Select(cat => new SluggedCategoriesViewModel
    {
      CategoryNameSlugged = Helpers.Slugify(cat.Category_Name),
      CategoryId = cat.Category_Id // etc
    });
```

Comment: `.Category_Name` from `db.bm_product_categories` was not found — what do I have to do?

Comment: Oh, Stuart, thanks! But my `Slugify()` method has a problem: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Slugify(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`. What do you think about this?

Comment: My bad again ... you will need to materialize your db.bm_product_categories before projecting it. Updated.

Comment: No problem, Stuart. But, in my view, how will be the Model?

Comment: Oh, thanks! Thank you so much, really really! Just one last question: this internal classe — what is the best place to put it?

Comment: I would suggest you create a new folder in your MVC project called 'ViewModels' and put classes like this there (the namespace might change).

Comment: Okay! Oh, an unforeseen happened... I do not know how @model, at View, have to be — can you clarify this for me? Anyway, thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<bm_product_categories> list = new List<bm_product_categories>();

foreach(string name in list.Select(x => x.Category_Name))
{ 
    slugifiedList.Add(name.Slugify()); // make extension method
}
```

or copy the `List<bm_product_categories>` and change the Category_Name property