# Sending complex data type to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm aware that this is basic but then again I couldn't figure out answer for this one ...

I would like to send string and int value as one ViewData value to View

```
ViewData["TypeOfPaymentSelected"] = new { StringName = Enum.GetName(typeof(PaymentType), payment), IntValue = payment };
```

but I do not know how to cast it inside View.

If I'm still in controller I would simple access is as

```
varName.StringName 
varName.IntValue
```

I know how to make ViewModel classes and cast it in View, I know I can send this as two ViewData values etc but I thought this can be done simpler
and obvioulsy I lack basic C# knowledge

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: @ViewBag.TypeOfPaymentSelected.StringName will not work

Comment: @ViewData["TypeOfPaymentSelected"].StringName

Comment: @Esko RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'IntValue'

Comment: @iivkovic Hmm yeah, you need to do @ViewData.Eval("TypeOfPaymentSelected.StringName"), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4680966/2674937)

Comment: @Esko yup ... thanks mate ... if I only knew that I was actually sending anonymous type :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anonymous types if you want but then you need to use for example Eval-method to access it in the view:

```
@ViewData.Eval("TypeOfPaymentSelected.StringName")
```

More info in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223713/can-i-pass-an-anonymous-type-to-my-asp-net-mvc-view/4680966#4680966)

Preferred way would be to use a model so that everything will be strongly typed.

Example:

```
namespace Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string StringName;
        public int IntValue;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["TypeOfPaymentSelected"] = new MyModel { StringName = "test", IntValue = 5 };
    return View();
}
```

And in View:

```
@(((Models.MyModel)ViewData["TypeOfPaymentSelected"]).StringName)
```