# Object does not contain "fullname" LINQ error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

I am a beginner to MVC and using Linq. So any help would be much appreciated.

So I have this LINQ statement to select and join my 3 tables,

```
OnlineRegistrationDBEntities1 dbEvents = new OnlineRegistrationDBEntities1();

var displayRegisteredEvents = (from x in dbEvents.Registers
                              join c in dbEvents.clients on x.email equals c.email
                              join e in dbEvents.events on x.eventname equals e.eventname
                              select new 
                              {
                                  fullname = c.fullname,
                                  eventname = e.eventname,
                                  email = c.email,
                                  guestnumber = x.guestnumber,
                                  payment_amount = x.payment_amount
                              });

return View(displayRegisteredEvents);
```

And I'm trying to display the result on an HTML table like this,

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var i in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@i.fullname</td>
                <td>@i.eventname</td>
                <td>@i.email</td>
                <td>@i.guestnumber</td>
                <td>@i.payment_amount</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="modalLink btn btn-danger" data-id="@i.email" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
                        Delete
                    </button>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</tbody>
```

However, when I run the program an error occurs saying:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'fullname'

Any idea what's wrong? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the definition of your Model in view?

Comment: Hi, good sir thank you for the help. You mean you wanna see the Model of my project?

Comment: No, it should be definition of your model in cshtml like `@model IEnumerable<Domain.Models.YourEntityName>`, could you please share it.

Comment: Oh ok. No, I didn't use any definition.

Comment: Should I put one?

Comment: So, where this model in `@foreach (var i in Model)` comes from then?

Comment: Oh in my controller I added my model library like this, using OnlineEventRegistration.Models;

Comment: You return IEnumerable anonymus objects from controller, so you can add `@model IEnumerable<dynamic>` to view

Comment: I see. I'll try that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please let me know after try whether it solves your problem or not, so that I can add this to an answer.

Comment: Hi sir, I tried adding that @model IEnumerable<dynamic>  to my view, it still outputs the same error.

Comment: What do you see when you put debug inside of foreach, what is the type of `Model` and do you have data in model?

Comment: @model IEnumerable<OnlineEventRegistration.Models.Register> that is my definition and that model contains the FK of my other two table.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`5[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Double]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[OnlineEventRegistration.Models.Register]'.. That is the error when I run it sir.

Comment: You need to create new POCO class and return it from controller, I have added an answer plase check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `anonymous` types, from: [Anonymous View Models in ASP.NET MVC Using Dynamics](https://www.gregshackles.com/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/)

> The answer here lies in the fact that anonymous classes are internal
>   by default, meaning they are only accessible to the assembly in which
>   they were created. Once you cross that assembly boundary, it gets
>   treated as a regular object

I suggest you that create a new POCO class then pass it to view instead of using `anonymous` types:

```
public class OnlineRegistrationViewModel
{
    public string fullname { get; set; }

    public string eventname { get; set; }

    public string email { get; set; }

    public string guestnumber { get; set; }

    public string payment_amount { get; set; }
}
```

And in your controller you need to return `List<OnlineRegistrationViewModel>`:

```
OnlineRegistrationDBEntities1 dbEvents = new OnlineRegistrationDBEntities1();

var displayRegisteredEvents = (from x in dbEvents.Registers
                              join c in dbEvents.clients on x.email equals c.email
                              join e in dbEvents.events on x.eventname equals e.eventname
                              select new OnlineRegistrationViewModel
                              {
                                  fullname = c.fullname,
                                  eventname = e.eventname,
                                  email = c.email,
                                  guestnumber = x.guestnumber,
                                  payment_amount = x.payment_amount
                              }).ToList();

return View(displayRegisteredEvents);
```

In your view you need to declare `Model`:

```
@model List<OnlineRegistrationViewModel>
```

See these references:

- https://www.gregshackles.com/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/
- [Can I pass an anonymous type to my ASP.NET MVC view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223713/can-i-pass-an-anonymous-type-to-my-asp-net-mvc-view)